# How to modify a dict in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I would like to modify this data using Python from

```json
{
    "date":<curdate>,
    "name":["","",""],
    "id":[",","]
}
```

to

```json
{
    "date":<currdate>,
    "inputs":{
        "name":["","",""], 
        "id":[",","]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assign the dictionary elements to the appropriate elements in a new dictionary.

```
new_dict = { "date": old_dict["date"],
             "inputs": {
                "name": old_dict["name"],
                "id": old_dict["id"]
              }
            }
```